# Having a same function for the same event but different objects jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a dynamically LI with jquery.

I have this jquery for changing the names of the li. I don't want to create a new function with the ID of the li for doing this. I don't consider this the best way of doing it. Imaging I add 100 li, I will have 100 functions. Which will be the best way of doing this.

I have my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/DiegoTc/dXX9G/

```
<div class="col-md-3 well">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="myTab">
<li id="pTabP" class="active">
    <a href="#tab_preview" data-toggle="pill">
        <span  id ="tabPr1" class="display">Preview Card</span>
        <input type="text" class="edit" style="display:none"/>
    </a>
</li>
<li id="fTab">
    <a href="#tab_GInfo" data-toggle="pill">
        <span  id ="tabG1" class="display">General Info</span>
        <input type="text" class="edit" style="display:none"/>
    </a>
</li>


 $("#pTabP").dblclick(function(){
   $("#tabPr1").hide().siblings(".edit").show().val($("#tabPr1").text()).focus();
 });
 $("#fTab").dblclick(function(){
   $("#tabG1").hide().siblings(".edit").show().val($("#tabG1").text()).focus();
 });
 $(".edit").focusout(function(){
    $(this).hide().siblings(".display").show().text($(this).val());
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an edit_text class to each span. Then once you double click it it will automatically find the textbox and show it.

I'm pretty sure this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/dXX9G/3/

```
$(this).hide().siblings(".edit").show().val($(this).text()).focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
function getDblClickHandler (targetSelector) {
    return function () {
        var $target = $('#' + targetSelector);
        $target.hide();
        $target.siblings(".edit")
          .show()
          .val($target.text())
          .focus();
    };
}

$("#pTabP").dblclick(getDblClickHandler('#tabPr1'));
$("#fTab").dblclick(getDblClickHandler('#tabG1'));
```

Or, even more compact:

```
var mappings = [
   { from: '#pTabP', to: '#tabPr1'},
   { from: '#fTab', to: '#tabG1'}
];

$.each(mappings, function (k, mapping) {
    $(mapping.from).dblclick(getDblClickHandler(mapping.to));
});
```

Comment: But if I start to create more li
I will had to add more
$("#fTab").dblclick(getDblClickHandler('tabG1'));
So it means I will have the same issue.

Comment: I don't know exactly what issue you mean, but in my second version you only have to add one line per li.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        $(".nav li")
        .on("dblclick", function (e) {
            $("span", this).hide()
                .siblings(".edit").show()
                .val($("span", this).text())
                .focus();
            return $(e.currentTarget.nodeName).each(function (i, el) {
                $(el).not($(e.currentTarget)).find("span").show()
                    .siblings(".edit").hide()
            })
        });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/LX8c4/